# Inno Setup : Pin icons to start screen in Windows 8.1?

Tags: icons, inno-setup, windows-8.1

My Inno Setup script includes these lines (and some similar ones):

```
Name: "{group}\vDosWP51"; Filename: "{app}\vDos WP51.exe"; Components: InstallForWP51
Name: "{commondesktop}\vDosWP51"; Filename: "{app}\vDosWP51.exe"; Components: InstallForWP51; Tasks: desktopicon51
Name: "{commonprograms}\vDosWP51"; Filename: "{app}\vDosWP51.exe"; Components: InstallForWP51; Tasks: desktopicon51
```

When I run the installer on XP or Windows 7, it works as expected. Under Windows 8.1, it creates icons in the list that you can get to by clicking the down arrow in the Start screen, but it doesn't pin the icon to the Start screen itself.

Is it possible to pin the icon to the Start screen via Inno Setup? From what I read online, it seems that it should be possible, but I can't make it work.

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I should have read around more carefully. The answer is that it can't be done under Windows 8.1 unless you modify Group Policies or do other things that are possible on a corporate level but not for an installer like this one. I hope this answer saves someone else the trouble of looking for it.